# Troubles using koma-moderncv

Tags: koma-script

I am some trouble writing a CV using *koma-moderncv* package. I am running MikTex 2.9 with TexnicCenter RC 1. I have installed the package via the package manager that comes along with MikTex. After doing this I downloaded and opened the example provided at http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-moderncvclassic. With the exception that I modified the options of babel and csquotes I have touched nothing. Never the less I get the following warnings when compiling:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastpage' on page 1 undefined on input line 138.

[1


{C:/Users/john.doe/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `lastpage' on page 2 undefined on input line 148.

[2]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 151.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 154.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 154.
(C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\Ansoegning\Skabelon\cvbasic.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 154.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 154.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `cvbasic.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: E64A0148F1EE05FA86DCDCCFFE737411;205.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                cvbasic
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

The result seems to be that I don't get the correct page-numbering. I am running `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`. In the `bibtex` step I get the errors `I found no \citation commands---while reading...`, `I found no \bibdata commands---while reading...` and `I found no \bibstyle commands---while reading...`

Has anyone experienced similar problems and what was the solution?

Comment: Look at the output: `Please (re)run Biber on the file`. Your using biber and not bibtex. If you want to use the example with bibtex, you have to change the `backend=biber` in `biblatex` to `backend=bibtex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very important to read the warning message carefully. In your case it's

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                cvbasic
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

That means you have loaded the package `biblatex` with the option `backend=biber`.

So you have to compile with:

```
(pdf)latex
biber
(pdf)latex
(pdf)latex
```

instead of `bibtex`. If you want to compile with `bibtex` you must change the option `backend` to `bibtex`.